# How do I get 100% on Wolfenstein: The New Order

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

How do you max out to 100% total completion on the Statistics page? Does collecting maps count towards 100%? Do you need all Achievement badges to get 100% (I'm using Steam) or is that not part of the calculation?

I've collected all the collectibles, completed all the side missions, and got all the weapon upgrades including the power boost for the LaserKraftWerk in Return to London Nautica.

The only Achievement I haven't got is completing the game on Uber, and I may have missed a map or two. Was wondering if I could hit 100% just by getting the maps, although I'll probably complete the game again on Uber and update what happened with the total completion statistic here later.

EDIT:

It turns out you only need to complete the final mission on Uber using chapter select to get the "Uber hero" badge on Steam. I'm still stuck on 99%. Guess I'll try collecting any maps I might have missed. Does anyone know if looking at the news clippings affects the completion percentage?

Comment: As far as I know, you need all maps, yes. Did you check achievements?

Comment: @Mario I know I missed a few news clippings. Does that count towards the completion statistic? The only other thing I can think of is that I skipped the Da'at Yichud chamber puzzle in the Fergus timeline, because I did it in the Wyatt timeline.

Comment: The random newspaper snippets? As far as I know, no. Only things found in your journal.